# How would I recursively merge two lists?

Tags: java, recursion

I figured out how to recursively reverse one list, but I'm trying to figure out how to merge two lists using recursion.

Avoiding using collections.

This is how its done to reverse the list, but I've been trying hard on how to merge two and I can't figure it out at all, which is why I'm asking people more skilled them ne.

```
public class Test {

    public static class Node {



            public Node next;
            public String name;

            public Node(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
            }

    }

    public static void reverse(Node previous, Node current) {

        if (current.next != null) {

            Node next= current.next;
            reverse(current, next);
        }

            if (previous == null) {
            // this was the start node
                    current.next= null;
        } else {
            //reverse
            current.next= previous;
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Node n1= new Node("A");
            Node n2= new Node("B");
            Node n3= new Node("C");
            Node n4= new Node("D");


            n1.next= n2;
            n2.next= n3;
            n3.next= n4;


            Node cursor= n1;
            while (cursor != null) {
                    System.out.println(cursor.name);
                    cursor= cursor.next;
            }


            reverse(null, n1);

            cursor= n4;
            while (cursor != null) {
                    System.out.println(cursor.name);
                    cursor= cursor.next;
```

I'm quite stumped. Even if I don't deserve a full and answer I just would like to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Please clarify. Give us code you have written, tell us what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list1.add(2);
        list1.add(5);
        list1.add(8);

        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list2.add(1);
        list2.add(4);
        list2.add(9);

        List<Integer> mergeList = mergeList(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(mergeList));
    }

    private static List<Integer> mergeList(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
        if (list1.size() == 0)
            return list2;
        if (list2.size() == 0)
            return list1;

        ArrayList result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (list1.get(0) < list2.get(0))// sorting
            result.add(list1.remove(0));
        else
            result.add(list2.remove(0));

        result.addAll(mergeList(list1, list2));

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Sorted Output**

```
[[1, 4, 9, 2, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: Wow. This is perfect, I'm curious about something, when would this be more efficient than using Collections.swap

Comment: @METEORITES i suppose `List.addAll()` might help you, it will just add the elements while increasing capacity